# Meteor Render Data from Remote API Call

Tags: api, asynchronous, meteor

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to render data from Fieldbook via their API into a Meteor template. I can successfully complete the API call and have the data return, however by the time I wait for the async API call my template has already tried to render my table of this data. I'm trying to use a reactive-table package (https://atmospherejs.com/aslagle/reactive-table) to render the data from the call. Is there a way to accomplish this goal? Thanks for any help.

HTML Template:

```
<template name="customers">
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight row  border-bottom white-bg dashboard-header">
        <h1>Customers</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-new-po">New Customer</button>
            &nbsp;
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-new-wo">New Contact</a>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-view-po">View Customers</button>
            &nbsp;
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-view-wo">View Contacts</a>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        {{> reactiveTable settings=customerTableSettings rowsPerPage=25}}
    </div>
</template>
```

JS File:

```
import './customers.html';
import swal from 'sweetalert2';

var Fieldbook = require('node-fieldbook');

Template.customers.onCreated(function listsShowPageOnCreated() {
    var book = new Fieldbook({
        username: '{fieldbook key name}',
        password: '{fieldbook password}',
        book: '{bookId}'
    });

    book.getSheet('customers').then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.data.customers = data;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });

});

Template.customers.helpers({
    customerTableSettings: function() {
        return {
            collection: this.customers,
            class: 'table table-striped table-hover col-sm-12 eventsTable',
            fields: [ 
                { key: 'short_name', label: 'Short Name', },
            ]
        }
    },
});

Template.customers.events({

});

Template.customers.rendered = function(){
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the code in onRendered:

```
Template.customers.onRendered(function() {
...code here
});
```

For example, in my app, I use handsontable, and this is how I import it after the data is ready.

```
Template.page.onRendered(function() {
   import('../hands.js').then(({default: Handsontable}) => {
   let hot_scroll_data = Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(250, 40);
   let hot_scroll = document.getElementById('hot_scroll');
   let hot_scroll_init = new Handsontable(hot_scroll,{
      data: data,
      stretchH: 'all',
      rowHeaders: true,
      columns: dynamicColumns
  });
})
```